# Testar funções com Jest e Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, react, jest

Como posso testar essa função com Jest e Enzyme?

```
addProducts = id => {
   toast.success("Product added", {
      position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT
   });
   history.push(`/product/${id}`);
};
```

Eu estava usando esse trecho de código, mas não foi suficiente ...

```
it("Must return added addProduct with success message", () => {
   const componente = shallow(<AddProduct />);

   const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "addProducts");

   expect(spy).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Podes mostrar mais código? o que é `wrapper` por exemplo?

Comment: Victor, não é uma resposta para sua pergunta, mas fica como sugestão: Use o react-testing-library. Você pode cair num erro de testar implementação e não o código em si por causa do Enzyme. De qualquer forma, para testar aí você precisa verificar se o toast apareceu na tela. Me parece que no seu código de testa vc está testando se aparece o addProducts e ele de fato não é renderizado e sim o toast.